# Scala: Throw Error vs Return Try?

Tags: scala

Should a Scala API ideally throw exceptions or return a Try value? Is there an official guideline regarding this?

```
def doSomethingMayThrow(): A = ???
def doSomethingWontThrow(): Try[A] = ???
```

Comment: Idiomatically, aka in a 'functionnal' way, it should use either `Try`, `Future` or other type wrapping success/error like scalaz validation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Never throw exceptions for recoverable errors.

Returning appropriate data structure representing a possible failure (a `Future`, a `Try`, an `Either` and so on) is always preferable than throwing exceptions in the wild. It will inform the caller about the possibility of a failure, and it will force them to manage it.

Exceptions should only be thrown for unrecoverable errors, such as hardware failures and similar.

Let's make an example:

```
def throwOnOdds(x: Int): Int =
   if (x % 2 == 0) x / 2 else throw new Exception("foo")

val x = throwOnOdds(41) + 2 // compiles and explodes at runtime
```

now, let's make it better

```
def throwOnOdds(x: Int): Try[Int] =
   if (x % 2 == 0) Success(x / 2) else Failure(new Exception("foo"))

val x = throwOnOdds(41) + 2 // doesn't compile
```

Not handling the failure leads to a compile-time error, which is way better than a runtime one. Here's how to handle it

```
throwOnOdds(41) match {
  case Success(n) => // do something with n
  case Failure(e) => // handle exception
}
```

Comment: In hindsight, this answer is flawed. First, it should be `Try[Int]` or `Either[Exception, Int]` not `Try[Exception, Int]`. Secondly, that will compile and run successfully and would only trigger a compile error if you tried to use `x` as an Int.

Comment: @clay wow! Now that I read it back there's so many wrong things, you're absolutely right. I fixed the answer, thanks for the catch!

Comment: "Never throw exceptions for recoverable errors" is a strong statement. Yet I can't find a counter argument to that. However it is objectionable whether "forcing caller to manage exception" is the right thing. Realistically I prefer to do `.get` on the `Try` in most of cases. By that I tell that I don't know how to deal with exception and signing off that it can crash the application or potentially corrupt results. Which is fine as long as you consider 'exception' as 'exceptional situation that should not occur under normal conditions'.

Answer (score 2):

See monadic datatypes. Using monadic datatypes is much more expressive and clear than throwing exceptions and would be the preferred way of declaratively handling all cases without unclear side effects.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)

The advantage of using a failure vs success and using map and flatMap to express the 'happy path' is that exceptions/failures become explicit in the chain.

Where you can tell if you call to doSomethingMayThrow might have a side effect (eg throwing an exception) it is very clear when you use a monadic datatype as a result.

It would help to look at a real world case. I'll use this as it is something i have worked on recently:

Consider a monadic future in a caching scenario - if the cache returns a result, you can process the result. If the cache does not return a result, then we can go to the actual service that we are trying to cache results from and we can express it very explicitly without any unclear implied side effects such as exception :

Here recoverWith is like flatMap on the error case (return a Future[Model] instead of the failure). recover is like map on the error case (return a model on the future instead of the failure). Then map takes whatever the resulting model is and processes it - all cases are clearly defined in the code so there is clarity of all cases and conditions in a single expression.

```
(userCacheActor ? GetUserModel(id="abc"))
    .recoverWith(userServiceActor ? GetUserModel(id="abc"))
    .recover(new ErrorModel(errorCode=100, body="service error")
    .map(x: Response => createHttpResponseFromModel(x))

def createHttpResponseFromModel(x: Model) => 
    x match {
        case model: ErrorModel => ??? 
        case model: UserModel => ???
    }
```

Again, everything is expressively notated - what to do with the failure of the cache hit, what to do if the service can't respond in that scenario, what to do with the result model at the end of all of the processing in any case.

Often flatMap is talked about as the 'plumber' of the monad or 'plumber' of the happy path. flatMap allows you to take another Monad and return it. So you can 'try' multiple scenarios and write the happy path code collecting any errors at the end.

```
scala> Option("Something").flatMap(x => Option( x + " SomethingElse"))
    .flatMap(x => None).getOrElse("encountered None somewhere")
res1: String = encountered None somewhere


scala> scala.util.Try("tried")
    .flatMap(x => scala.util.Try( x + " triedSomethingElse"))
    .flatMap(x => scala.util.Try{throw new Exception("Oops")})
    .getOrElse("encountered exception")
res2: String = encountered exception
```